# Stuck with induction Divisibility

Tags: induction, divisibility, solution-verification

I have seen many on the questions on here about induction divisibilty, but I haven't found any question that covers the doubt that I'm having. The preposition says: "For any integer n $\leq$-3, 8 divides 5<sup>−(n+2)</sup>+2(3<sup>-(n+3)</sup>)+1"
These are the steps I've done already

1. I prove that P(-3) is divisible by 8.
2. Then I assume that P(k) is divisible by 8 and write it as:
   5<sup>−(k+2)</sup>+2(3<sup>-(k+3)</sup>)+1 = 8m. Since the result is a multiple of 8
3. Then I need to prove P(k+1) is divisible by 8 (step that I'm stuck on). I did the following:
   5<sup>−(k+1+2)</sup>+2(3<sup>-(k+1+3)</sup>)+1
   Then I factored the first two terms to make them similar to P(k) so I can substitute for 8m:
   5<sup>−1</sup>5<sup>−(k+2)</sup>+2(3<sup>-(k+3)</sup>)3<sup>-1</sup>+1

And that's how far I've gotten. If only my exponents were positive I would have finished this proof long ago, but they aren't. I'm beginning to study proofs and I know these questions are really basic, but I've been trying to solve this on my own for 3 hours now and I haven't made any progress.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The preposition says: "For any integer n $\leq$-3, 8 divides 5<sup>−(n+2)</sup>+2(3<sup>-(n+3)</sup>)+1"

Let $m = -n$. Then $n \leq -3$ becomes $-n \geq 3 \iff m \geq 3$. Also, $-(n + 2) = -n - 2 = m - 2$. Finally, $-(n + 3) = -n - 3 = m - 3$. This means your proposition can now be equivalently stated as

> For any integer $m \ge 3$, prove $8$ divides $5^{m-2} + 2\left(3^{m-3}\right) + 1$.

Next, just follow the basic steps you outlined earlier, which you state you should now not have any problems with since you're dealing with non-negative exponents only.